# How do you change the number of product columns?

Tags: magento-1.9, html, local.xml, class

I want to change the number of products that are shown. But I don't want to hard code this into the theme.

This:

```
<ul class=​"products-grid products-grid--max-4-col first last odd">​…​</ul>​
```

should be transformed into this:

```
<ul class=​"products-grid products-grid--max-6-col first last odd">​…​</ul>​
```

It's a simple change. The `4` needs to become a `6`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is in fact, **how do you change the number of product columns**.

The line you wish to change is generated by this code:

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
```

that you can find in this file:

```
app\design\frontend\Your_Package\Your_Theme\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
```

**One simple way** to change the number of columns is to edit catalog.xml of your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/layout/catalog.xml
```

Find and edit the line that says:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

**Another simple way** to change columns count with a custom layout section in the categories: In the Custom Design tab for a category, enter this code in the Custom Layout Update field:

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
</reference>
```

You can find further reference in this video:
[Change magento column count in products grid list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNbV34v72a0)

**Another way** would be to edit the list.phtml file and replace this line:

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

with something like:

```
<?php $_columnCount = 6; ?>
```

Comment: I would double up-vote if it was possible. Great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on template path hints and find out what is rendering what you are looking to edit. You can edit that template directly.

In admin:
`System->Configuration->Developer->Advanced->Debug`

Turn it on then refresh your front end. The template will appear in the corner. Then find that template in your code set.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you mean this?

```
  jQuery.noConflict();  
 jQuery( '#product-grid-div')removeClass('product-grids-Max-4-cols')
 .addClass('product-grids-Max-6-cols');
```

Put iT somewhere in The bottom and add your own stuff.