# Change number of products shown per row in search results page

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, layout-update

How can I ***change the number of products shown per row in the search results page*** in Magento? The layout is currently three products per row and I would like it to be five products per row.

Would this be a change within the ***'catalogsearch.xml'*** file?

I have the following in my ***catalogsearch.xml*** file:

```
        <layout version="0.1.0">

            <default>
                <reference name="header">
                    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
                </reference>
                <reference name="footer_links">
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
                        <label>Search Terms</label>
                        <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
                        <title>Search Terms</title>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
                        <label>Advanced Search</label>
                        <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
                        <title>Advanced Search</title>
                    </action>
                </reference>
            </default>

            <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
                <label>Quick Search Form</label>
                <reference name="root">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-cms.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="left_first">
                    <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                        <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
                    </block>
                </reference>
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
                        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                            <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                            <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                            </block>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column_cms</layout><count>5</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                        </block>
                        <action method="setListOrders"/>
                        <action method="setListModes"/>
                        <action method="setListCollection"/>
                    </block>
                </reference>
            </catalogsearch_result_index>

            <catalogsearch_advanced_index translate="label">
                <label>Advanced Search Form</label>
                <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
                <reference name="root">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalogsearch"><title>Advanced Search</title></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml"/>
                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </reference>
            </catalogsearch_advanced_index>

        <!--
        Advanced search results
        -->

            <catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
                <label>Advanced Search Result</label>
                <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
                <!-- Mage_Catalogsearch -->
                <reference name="root">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-cms.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_result" name="catalogsearch_advanced_result" template="catalogsearch/advanced/result.phtml">
                        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                            <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                            <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                            </block>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column_cms</layout><count>5</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                        </block>
                        <action method="setListOrders"/>
                        <action method="setListModes"/>
                        <action method="setListCollection"/>
                    </block>
                </reference>
            </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

            <catalogsearch_term_popular translate="label">
                <label>Popular Search Terms</label>
                <remove name="right"/>
                <remove name="left"/>

                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="catalogsearch"><title>Search Terms</title></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="root">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="catalogsearch/term" name="seo.searchterm" template="catalogsearch/term.phtml"/>
                </reference>
            </catalogsearch_term_popular>

        </layout>
```

The catalog search is set to be 1column-cms layout but the column count is three when I'm looking for it to be five.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: you need to explain what you want and I think you should first google and then ask it. if you mean the columns per row you can do it in layout http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35957/how-do-you-change-the-number-of-product-columns

Comment: Thanks Negin updated - the answer you linked to doesn't work for me - but I've added my layout above.

Comment: please turn on your template path hints and let me know what is the phtml file, give me the whole path, then I will see if you are in the right xml file.

Comment: It appears to be list.phtml that contains the search results Negin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by adding the following code to the catalogsearch.xml file:

> ```
> <action method="setColumnCount"><count>6</count></action>
> ```

Thank you.